# Connect same app on different devices to the same database

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, ado

I have a C# winforms app and I want to install it on two or more devices,
but I want them to share the same database.
Any advice on how to do that?

Comment: That's a pity, but what's you question? what have you tried?

Comment: i have an app that's using a db and i want run it on more than one device but i want the app on any device to share one db so that when any one from any device makes changes to the db other app on other devices see the db changes .I have no idea how to do that

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea what to try

Comment: How are you connecting to database? What method are you using to retrive data? What database are you using? How is your database set up? Is your database accessible from the network? What is your connection string?... MORE DETAILS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too much general so I try give you general answer.

You're probably trying create app for more users which have shared database with data. Probably best choice is expose your shared database on server (by purpose - lan or wan) and connect to it from each device.

You should mention which db you are using, for example MySQL,MSSQL,...

Other thing is if you want have one db on each device which are modified off-line and are synchronized in time intervals but I dont thing thats good way how solve this situation.

I will update after you provide more info.

EDIT:
First thing you have to - public MSSQL server so application will be launched from device which is able to ping MSSQL server. 
Second you create connection to it from application, I provide you sample, you should modify it for best purpose in your situation (for example - instead of creating one connection for each query you should use connection pool, usage of transactions, etc...)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM [MyTable]";

        //db connection config
        DbConfigInfo Config = new DbConfigInfo()
                                  {
                                      ServerAddress = "MyServer",
                                      DbName = "MyDb",
                                      TrustedConnection = true
                                  };

        //db adapter for communication
        DbAdapter Adapter = new DbAdapter()
                                {
                                    DbConfig = Config
                                };

        //output with data
        DataTable MyDataTable;
        if (!Adapter.ExecuteSqlCommandAsTable(Query, out MyDataTable))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Occured!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }

        //do actions with your DataTable
    }   
}

public class DbAdapter
{
    //keeps connection info
    public DbConfigInfo DbConfig { get; set; }

    public bool ExecuteSqlCommandAsTable(string CmdText, out DataTable ResultTable)
    {
        ResultTable = null;

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(DbConfig.GetConnectionStringForMssql2008()))
            {
                SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdText, Conn);
                Conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable ReturnValue = new DataTable();
                ReturnValue.Load(Reader);

                ResultTable = ReturnValue;

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class DbConfigInfo
{
    public string ServerAddress { get; set; } //address of server - IP address or local name
    public string DbName { get; set; } //name of database - if you want create new database in query, set this to master
    public string User { get; set; } //user name - only if winauth is off
    public string Password { get; set; } //user password - only if winauth is off
    public bool TrustedConnection { get; set; } //if integrated windows authenticating under currently logged win user should be used 

    //creates conn string from data
    public string GetConnectionStringForMssql2008()
    {
        StringBuilder ConStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        ConStringBuilder.AppendFormat("Data Source={0};", ServerAddress)
                        .AppendFormat("Initial Catalog={0};", DbName);

        if (TrustedConnection)
        {
            ConStringBuilder.Append("Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
        else
        {
            ConStringBuilder.AppendFormat("User Id={0};", User)
                            .AppendFormat("Password={0};", Password));
        }

        return ConStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: im using sql server 2008